# Error trying to run an app in Qt

Tags: c++, macos, qt, libraries, iconv

I'm trying to run an application in Qt, but I'm getting the following error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv
  Referenced from: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
 in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

I'm using Qt 5.6 with the Qwt and Boost libraries (both installed by Homebrew) on OS X El Capitan 10.11.5.

Notes:

- The variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty.
- The file `libiconv.2.dylib` is in the `/opt/local/lib/` folder.

I'm new on OS X and I really don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem rebuilding the libraries Boost and Qwt and setting the correct path on my Qt project.

Note: I also had to copy the `.../qwt.frameworks` folder to the `/System/Library/Frameworks` folder.